# Set parent-child relationship in PHP

Tags: php, relatedto

I'm new to Craft but long time back-end php programmer. I'm trying to assign a parent-child (a ENTRY type to another ENTRY type) relationship in php based on some business rules.

I've got my child model, I can retrieve the parent as well, but can't manage to connect them. I set my relationship, so in the admin panel I can manage to do it manually.
[image]

In the code, I've got

```
$entry = Entry::find()
         ->section('systems')
         ->where(['content.field_systemtype' => ['=', $systemRecommended]])
         ->one();
error_log(print_r($entry->id,true)); // To show entry is found.`
```

**I've tried many things without success like:**

```
// $model->recommendedSystem->relatedTo($entry);

// $model->setFieldValue('recommendedSystem', $entry->id);
```

And maybe a few others last week.

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just to clear up a potential source of confusion: For Craft, the only 'real' parent-child relationships are the hierarchies in [Structures](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#structures) (a type of [Section](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries.html#section-types)). [Entry fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/entries-fields.html) and by extension [relations](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/relations.html) (including the `relatedTo` parameter) are technically many-to-many relations (even if you allow only one related entry in your `recommendedSystem` field).

The `relatedTo` parameter only exists for queries, you can't use it on an [Entry model](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-elements-entry.html).

Your second approach is the correct one, you can programmatically set field values using [craft\elements\Entry::setFieldValue](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-base-element.html#method-setfieldvalue). For entries fields, you need to pass an array of IDs. Also, make sure to save the element using the [craft\services\Elements::saveElement](https://docs.craftcms.com/api/v3/craft-services-elements.html#method-saveelement) to persist your changes in the database.

```php
$model->setFieldValue('recommendedSystem', [$entry->id]);
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($model);
```

If it's still not working: The `saveElement` method will run validation on the passed element by default and return a boolean to indicate success or failure. Afterwards, you can access any validation errors on the model using `$model->getErrors()`. If the field is not getting saved and you're not sure why, try dumping the output to find any errors that prevent the model from saving:

```php
$success = Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($model);
if (!$success) {
    Craft::dd($model->getErrors());
}
```

If you really want to, you can also just save the entry without validation like this:

```php
Craft::$app->elements->saveElement($model, false);
```

As a sidenote, if `$entry` and `$model` are the same entry, make sure to check the following checkbox in the settings of the `recommendedSystem` field: **Allow self relations**
Without this option, elements aren't allowed to relate to themselves, so trying to relate an element to itself through an entries field will silently fail.

Comment: What a nice explanation !
I tried to put my id as an ARRAY just like suggested and it WORKS !
So:
`$model->setFieldValue('recommendedSystem', [$entry->id]);` does the job.